# Get the co-ordinates of markup on image in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, annotate

I need to get the co-ordinates of markup(it may be circle, rectangle or any shapes) on image in cocoa. It would be starting `x,y` points when markup starts or the `x,y` points when markup ends.

Now I am to able to draw a shape on image, but I am unable to get the `x,y` points of that shape.

```
   [_imageView setCurrentToolMode: IKToolModeAnnotate];
```

This line of code I am using to draw a shape.

Can anybody help to solve this problem.